# How to remove [ ] closed bracket in djagno rest framework output

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

Is there any way to remove []  in the output when we run server using django.

I need output only in json format, I dont need open and closed bracket in start and end position of output

Here is my output after run the server :  http:127.0.0.1:8000/WBCIS/wbcis/

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "fruit": "Pomegranate",
        "district": "Pune",
        "taluka": "Haveli",
        "revenue_circle": "Uralikanchan",
        "sum_insured": 110000.0,
        "area": 12200.0,
        "farmer": 1836
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "fruit": "Guava",
        "district": "Pune",
        "taluka": "Haveli",
        "revenue_circle": "Uralikanchan",
        "sum_insured": 50000.0,
        "area": 1150.0,
        "farmer": 10
    }
]
```

this is my current output, but i want data in this format, like :

```
{
    {
        "id": 1,
        "fruit": "Pomegranate",
        "district": "Pune",
        "taluka": "Haveli",
        "revenue_circle": "Uralikanchan",
        "sum_insured": 110000.0,
        "area": 12200.0,


          "farmer": 1836
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "fruit": "Guava",
            "district": "Pune",
            "taluka": "Haveli",
            "revenue_circle": "Uralikanchan",
            "sum_insured": 50000.0,
            "area": 1150.0,
            "farmer": 10
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to remove [ ] brackets ?

Comment: You cant... you have an array of objects, you need to use the array syntax. Your second snippet isn't valid json.

Comment: @Sayse, okay thanks for clarification. I was thinking so much for that,

Answer (score 1):

The format you have requested is NOT valid JSON.

Currently you receive data in square brackets `[]` because you have *a list of elements*, ordered set of elements accessible by index. And this is valid JSON.

Curly brackets `{}` are used in dictionaries — sets of elements, accessible by keys.

So, if you want your elements to be placed in curly brackets, they should be put as values of some dictionary. But dictionary elements, of course, should have keys. I.e., data should like this:

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 1,
        "fruit": "Pomegranate",
        "district": "Pune",
        "taluka": "Haveli",
        "revenue_circle": "Uralikanchan",
        "sum_insured": 110000.0,
        "area": 12200.0,
        "farmer": 1836
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 2,
        "fruit": "Guava",
        "district": "Pune",
        "taluka": "Haveli",
        "revenue_circle": "Uralikanchan",
        "sum_insured": 50000.0,
        "area": 1150.0,
        "farmer": 10
    }
}
```

But. The data you currently have are in valid JSON format and are generally OK.

Comment: ,okay, in every output they give me square bracket, what should i do to remove that square brackets , because I want to load that data in html file, but square bracket give me problem

Comment: @KiranPrajapati if you want to render data to HTML — you don't need DRF. :) Just use ordinary Django views and templates.

Comment: @KiranPrajapati DRF is designed to use for REST APIs. Which use JSON as data format. If valid JSON is not what you want to get — probably you just don't need DRF.